# Save part of an 2D array into another 2D array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array which holds an ASCII map. I have another function called `botLook()` which needs to store a section of the map into another 2D array. This is a section of the map which the bot can see. I have written a function so far but keep getting out of bounds errors. The bot can see a radius of 2 around its self.

```
public char[][] botLook3(){
    char[][] show = new char[5][5];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int x = posX-2; i<posX+3; x++){
        for (int y = posY-2; y<posY+3; y++){
            if (i>=0 && i<rows && j>=0 && j<cols){
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(j);
                if(Math.abs(posX-i)+Math.abs(posY-j)<4){
                    show[x][y] = myWorld[i][j];
                }else{
                    show[x][y] =  'X';
                }
            }else{
                show[x][y] = '?';
            }
        i++;
        }
    j++;
    }
    return show;
}
```

This is the error message I am getting;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
at GameLogic.botLook2(GameLogic.java:67)
at PlayGame.main(PlayGame.java:32)
```

Thanks, Ciaran.

Comment: what is posX & posY ?

Comment: The current position of the bot in the 2D array.

Comment: posX and posY initail with what value ?

Comment: Please give some demo values for `posX`,  `posY`, `rows` and `cols`, *and* `myWorld`. Pretty hard to help with so much missing information.

Comment: posX and posY can be anywhere within the map the idea is that you are not allowed to see the whole map but a 5x5 grid in which you are in the center. If you are next to a wall then outside of the wall would be represented as a '?'.

Answer (score 0):

Since i and j are both set relative to posX and posY, if posX or posY are greater than 5, at some point in the loop you are going to refer to an index in the array greater than 5 and therefore be out-of-bound

Comment: I have changed the code now but I am still getting the same error. Edited the code in the question to show what I have changed.

Comment: Your code still is dependent on posX and posY. Take this for an example: posX = 0 and posY = 0. In this case, during your first iteration, you will pas your if statement and try to access show[-2][-2] which, obviously, is not allowed and out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is occurring because either of the index value  i or j in the loop is going beyond the size of at least one of the two 2d arrays show and myworld.
Please check the values of i & j in the loop through.

```
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public char[][] botLook(){
    char[][] show = new char[][]{
        new char[]{ '?','?','?','?','?'},
        new char[]{ '?','?','?','?','?'},
        new char[]{ '?','?','?','?','?'},
        new char[]{ '?','?','?','?','?'},
        new char[]{ '?','?','?','?','?'}
    };
    for (int i = Math.max( 2 - posX, 0); i< Math.min( (cols + 2) - posX, 5); i++){
        for (int j = Math.max( 2 - posY, 0); i< Math.min( (rows + 2) - posY, 5); i++){
            if(Math.abs(i - 2) + Math.abs(j - 2) < 4){
                show[i][j] = myWorld[posX - 2 + i][ posY - 2 + j];
            }else{
                show[i][j] =  'X';
            }
        }
    }
    return show;
}
```